# Why does my WPF MVVM Command not working?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command

I have a very simple WPF form with one field, a button and a combobox (an extract from the bigger view)

I want to execute a command on hitting the button in order to perfom a search and fill the combobox. This worked fine until i changed something on the form and now it doesn't work anymore.
I tried to get rid of my former changes but nothing happens: i still can't execute the command behind the button.

Any ideas?

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid  Name="SelectionGrid" 
               DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
               Height="Auto"                
               Width="Auto"
               DataContext="{Binding Test, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Content="Referenz Kollege "/>
        <TextBox Name="RefPartnerTextBox"                          
                     Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
                     Margin="0,3,0,0"                           
                     Text="{Binding RefPartner}"
                     DataContext="{Binding Test, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                     ToolTip="{Binding TooltipReferenzpartner}"                         
                       >
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SearchRefPartnerCommand}" Key="Return" />
                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SearchRefPartnerCommand}" Key="Enter" />
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button 
                        Command="{Binding SearchRefPartnerCommandNew}" 
                        >
                <Image   
                            Source="..\Resources\Images\Search.jpg" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" 
                            Stretch="UniformToFill"                                                                                       
                            Height="20" Width="20"
                        />
            </Button>
            <ComboBox Name="RefPartnerCombobox"  
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Partners}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPartner}"
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                          Visibility="{Binding Path=RefPartnerComboVisible}"
                          Margin="0,3,0,0"
                />
        </StackPanel>
        <!---->
    </Grid>
```

`

ViewModel  "TestModel"

```
  private ObservableCollection<PartnerModel> _partners;
    public ObservableCollection<PartnerModel> Partners {
        get {
            return _partners;
        }
        set {
            if (value == _partners) return;
            _partners = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Partners");
        }
    }

    //
    private PartnerModel _selectedRefPartner;
    public PartnerModel SelectedRefPartner {
        get {
            return _selectedRefPartner;
        }
        set {
            if (value == _selectedRefPartner) return;
            _selectedRefPartner = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedRefPartner");
        }
    }

    #endregion Listen für Combos


    private string _refPartner;
    public string RefPartner {
        get {
            return _refPartner;
        }
        set {
            if (value == _refPartner) return;
            _refPartner = value;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_refPartner)) {
                if (Partners != null) {
                    Partners.Clear();                        
                }
                RefPartnerComboVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("RefPartner");
        }
    }

    private Visibility _refPartnerComboVisible;
    public Visibility RefPartnerComboVisible {
        get {
            return _refPartnerComboVisible;
        }
        set {
            if (value == _refPartnerComboVisible) return;
            _refPartnerComboVisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("RefPartnerComboVisible");
        }
    }


    #region Commands
    public ICommand SearchRefPartnerCommand { get; private set; }

    #endregion Commands
    

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public TestModel(INewUserService userService, IBasicDataService basicData) {
        _userService = userService;
        _basicDataService = basicData;

        InitAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitAsync() {
        
        RefPartner = string.Empty;
        RefPartnerComboVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;


        InitCommands();
    }

    #region Collections
    private ObservableCollection<PartnerModel> ConvertPartnerListIntoObservableCollection(List<PartnerModel> sourceList) {
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<PartnerModel>();
        if (sourceList == null) {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (var item in sourceList) {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
        return collection;
    }
    #endregion Collections

    private void InitCommands() {
        SearchRefPartnerCommand = new RelayCommand(async o => await SearchRefPartnerButtonClickAsync("SearchRefPartnerButtonClick"));
        
    }


    private async Task SearchRefPartnerButtonClickAsync(string v) {
        _logger.Info($"Start {nameof(SearchRefPartnerButtonClickAsync)}");
        RefPartnerComboVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        
        var parts = RefPartner.Split(',');

        Partners = ConvertPartnerListIntoObservableCollection(await _basicDataService.GetPartners(parts[0].Trim(), parts[1].Trim()));

        RefPartnerComboVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        SelectedRefPartner = Partners.First();
    }
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null) {
        if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        _execute(parameter ?? "<N/A>");
    }

}
```

Comment: In XAML, you have two commands bound.
But only one command is declared in the ViewModel.
There is no commnew `SearchRefPartnerCommandNew` in the ViewModel.

Comment: Ok, this was a typo.

Comment: But it doesn't work either...

Comment: The second possible error is the asynchronous initialization of the command property value.
If the duration of the method is long, it is possible that the binding in the button is created before the command is written to the property.
You can check this in the Dynamic Property Browser.
Look in it the value of the Command property of the button.

Comment: Nope, i removed the async declaration and assigned a "normal" void method but still the same error...

Comment: Have you looked at the value of the Command property?
Is there a command or is it null?

Comment: The property has a assigned command it is not null

Comment: OK!
Now for the next step.
Put a breakpoint on the lambda `o => await SearchRefPartnerButtonClickAsync (" SearchRefPartnerButtonClick ")`.
And check: when the button is pressed, will it stop or not?
If so, put a breakpoint inside the `SearchRefPartnerButtonClickAsync` method and check step by step how it is executed.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the lambda expression but it is never executed. When i stopped a at any other point and check if the command is still assigned i see that the relay command is still assigned. but by hitting the button nothing happens like it is not assigned from the view side.  Although i do not changed the xaml it seems that the command is not assigned to view.

Comment: Then, with a high degree of probability, you have confusion between VM instances.
More code is needed to figure out the reason.
Minimal solution to reproduce the problem is desirable.
Upload it to GitHub and provide a link.